# How do I use the new Twitter API 1.1 search in Python?

Tags: python, django, json, api, twitter

As you will all know, Twitter is transitioning to a new API (1.1) and the old one (1.0) is facing blackouts and eventually termination.

I'm working on a group project using Python/[Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29), and it seems that none of the big Python Twitter libraries are using API 1.1. I could just directly interface with the API without using a Python interface, but I have problems with that due to needing to use the [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) login.

So I have two questions.

1. Is there a Python library which support Twitter API 1.1?
2. If we directly interface with the new API as in the following URL, how do we get it to work considering we need to be logged in with OAuth?

   URL: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=#freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4`

Comment: Have you tried to search for any libraries that support Twitter API 1.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Twitter module works. You can use it to ask Twitter to authenticate, go to the Twitter website, enter user and password, and save a token on your computer.

I use this code to search Twitter statuses (real-time search is a bit different than standard Twitter search).

#### Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import twitter
import json
import csv

from twitter.oauth import write_token_file, read_token_file
from twitter.oauth_dance import oauth_dance

def login():
    # Go to http://twitter.com/apps/new to create an app and get these items.
    # See also http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token.

    APP_NAME = 'xxx'
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxx'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx'
    TOKEN_FILE = '/token.txt'

    try:
        (oauth_token, oauth_token_secret) = read_token_file(TOKEN_FILE)
    except IOError, e:
        (oauth_token, oauth_token_secret) = oauth_dance(APP_NAME, CONSUMER_KEY,
                CONSUMER_SECRET)
        print e.errno
        print e

        if not os.path.isdir('out'):
            os.mkdir('out')

        write_token_file(TOKEN_FILE, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)

    auth=twitter.oauth.OAuth(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret,CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    return twitter.TwitterStream(auth = auth, secure = True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    t = login()
    res = t.statuses.filter(track = "search text")

    res_list = []
    tweetfields = set()
    for r in res:
        if len(res_list)<100:
            print len(res_list)
            res_list.append(r)
            tweetfields = tweetfields.union(r.keys())
        else:
            break

    fname = '/results.csv'
    f = open(fname,'w')
    dw = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=list(tweetfields))
    dw.writeheader()

    for r in res_list:
        dw.writerow({k:v.encode('utf8') if isinstance(v,unicode) else v for k,v in r.items()})
    f.close()

    print [result['text'] for result in res_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we directly interface with the new API as following, how do we get it to work considering we need to be logged in with OAuth?

```
>>> import twitter
>>> client = twitter.Api(username='yourusername', password='yourpassword')
>>> update = client.PostUpdate('The Twitter API is easy')
```